# Error while using Firebase Google_signin option in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-signin

im trying to use Google sign-in option in my project,my app is loading fine and its displaying the accounts which already exists in the mobile but when i click on it, it is not signing in and switching to new screen and also its throwing me an error.

Here's my code:

```
final FirebaseAuth _firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  final GoogleSignIn _googlSignIn = new GoogleSignIn();

  Future<FirebaseUser> _signIn(BuildContext context) async {

    Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(new SnackBar(
      content: new Text('Sign in'),
    ));

    final GoogleSignInAccount googleUser = await _googlSignIn.signIn();
    final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth =await googleUser.authentication;

    final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(
      accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
      idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
    );

    FirebaseUser userDetails = (await _firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)).user;
    ProviderDetails providerInfo = new ProviderDetails(userDetails.providerId);

    List<ProviderDetails> providerData = new List<ProviderDetails>();
    providerData.add(providerInfo);

    UserDetails details = new UserDetails(
      userDetails.providerId,
      userDetails.displayName,
      userDetails.photoUrl,
      userDetails.email,
      providerData,
    );
    Navigator.push(
      context,
      new MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => new Profile(detailsUser: details),
      ),
    );
    return userDetails;
```

this is my second screens code where im trying to retrieve the user's details in this screen

```
final UserDetails detailsUser;

  Profile({Key key, @required this.detailsUser}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final GoogleSignIn _gSignIn =  GoogleSignIn();

    return  Scaffold(
        appBar:  AppBar(
          title:  Text(detailsUser.userName),
          automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
          actions: <Widget>[
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(
                FontAwesomeIcons.signOutAlt,
                size: 20.0,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
              onPressed: (){
                _gSignIn.signOut();
                print('Signed out');
                Navigator.pop(context);

              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
        body:Center(child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            CircleAvatar(
              backgroundImage:NetworkImage(detailsUser.photoUrl),
              radius: 50.0,
            ),
            SizedBox(height:10.0),
            Text(
              "Name : " + detailsUser.userName,
              style:  TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.black,fontSize: 20.0),
            ),
            SizedBox(height:10.0),
            Text(
              "Email : " + detailsUser.userEmail,
              style:  TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.black,fontSize: 20.0),
            ),
            SizedBox(height:10.0),
            Text(
              "Provider : " + detailsUser.providerDetails,
              style:  TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.black,fontSize: 20.0),
            ),
```

The error which i was getting whenever i click on the google account is given below:

```
W/Gralloc3( 4066): mapper 3.x is not supported
D/FlutterView( 4066): Attaching to a FlutterEngine: io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine@46e60ce
D/FlutterView( 4066): Already attached to this engine. Doing nothing.
W/ActivityThread( 4066): handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy@7725948
I/flutter ( 4066): PlatformException(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10: , null)
W/ActivityThread( 4066): handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy@70d26c1
I/flutter ( 4066): PlatformException(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10: , null)
W/ActivityThread( 4066): handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy@4acc1c
I/flutter ( 4066): PlatformException(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10: , null)
D/FlutterView( 4066): Detaching from a FlutterEngine: io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine@46e60ce
```

Answer (score 0):

ApiException: 10

> Certain Google Play services (such as Google Sign-in and App Invites)
>   require you to provide the SHA-1 of your signing certificate so we can
>   create an OAuth2 client and API key for your app

**How to add SHA-1 into Firebase project:**

**In Android Studio:** Double click `signingReport`: -> get SHA1

[image: Get SHA1 from Android Studio]

**Check result in Run window**

[image: Check result in Run window]

**Open project setting Firebase:**

[image: Add SHA1 to Firebase project setting]

Comment: where can i find this file in my project

Comment: @myname you run task in Gradle Window (Android Studio), then view result in Run window. I edited my answer with Run window result for you.